# Number Theory Taxicab Number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How to prove that there are infinite taxicab numbers?
ok i was reading this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number#Known_taxicab_numbers
and thought of this question..any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to show that there are infinitely many positive integers which are representable as the sum of two cubes, e.g., see the article [Characterizing the Sum of Two Cubes](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcs.uwaterloo.ca%2Fjournals%2FJIS%2FVOL6%2FBroughan%2Fbroughan25.pdf&ei=xOAGVY7dN8PeOP7VgOAF&usg=AFQjCNG8rHk5ueNrG5WD97gCXepEIjun7w&bvm=bv.88198703,d.ZWU) by K.A. Broughan (2003). If we require a representation as the sum of two cubes in at least $N\ge 2$ different ways, then the result is more difficult to show; and the proof uses the theory of elliptic curves etc. For a good survey, see the article [Taxicabs and sum of two cubes](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.maa.org%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fpdf%2Fupload_library%2F22%2FFord%2Fsilverman331-340.pdf&ei=zeEGVbFkhsw9zsWAsAY&usg=AFQjCNGrGtbbjX5GN4HF32EDTcaJQDHMPg&bvm=bv.88198703,d.ZWU) by J. H. Silverman. In particular, the following result due to K. Mahler is discussed:

**Theorem(Mahler):** There is a constant $c>0$ such that for infinitely many positive integers $m$, the number of positive integer solutions to the equation $x^3+y^3=m$ exceeds $c(\log(m))^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 2):

Use Ramanujan's identity that 
$$\left(x^2+7xy-9y^2\right)^3+\left(2x^2-4xy+12y^2\right)^3=\left(2x^2+10y^2\right)^3+\left(x^2-9xy-y^2\right)^3$$

Reference:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation3rdPowers.html