# Numbers that can be expressed as the sum of two cubes in exactly two different ways

Tags: number-theory

It seems known that there are infinitely many numbers that can be expressed as a sum of two positive cubes in at least two different ways (per the answer to this post: [Number Theory Taxicab Number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192338/number-theory-taxicab-number)).

We know that

$$1729 = 10^3+9^3 = 12^3 + 1^3,$$

and I am wondering if there are infinitely many numbers like this that can be expressed as the sum of two positive cubes in *exactly* two ways?

In fact, are there even any other such numbers?

EDIT:
As provided by MJD in the comments section, here are other examples:
$$4104 = 2^3+16^3 = 9^3+15^3,$$
$$13832 = 20^3+18^3=24^3+2^3,$$
$$20683 = 10^3 +27^3 = 19^3 +24^3.$$

Comment: A computer search should quickly find more examples. Because the roots are required to be positive, if you find that 192837465 (or whatever) is the sum of cubes in two ways, you only need to examines the sums of cubes of numbers up to $\sqrt[3]{192837465}$ to verify that no other pairs add up to 192837465. This is easy.

Comment: The computer instantly finds further examples $4104 = 2^3+16^3 = 9^3+15^3, 13832 = 8\cdot 1729, 20683 = 10^3+27^3 = 19^3+24^3$, 32832, 39312, 40033, ….

Comment: FYI : [OEIS A001235](http://oeis.org/A001235)

Comment: @mathlove thanks, though that is a list of numbers that has at least two representations as a sum of two cubes. I see that some of MJD's examples are on that list as well.

Comment: @MJD thanks, I have included some of your findings in my post.

Comment: [Here's the first thousand examples](https://gist.github.com/mjdominus/cc67be601f9e178b3ee7).

Comment: @HowDoIMath: See [**Leonhard Euler**, *Disquitiones Artithmeticae*, Vol. I, Ch. $272$, Pag. $556-576$](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6952c/f599.highres).

Comment: Just to add, there are also solutions where $a^3 - b^3$ can be the sum of two cubes in two different ways, for $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. $$46^3 - 37^3 = 46683 = 27^3 + 30^3 = 3^3 + 36^3$$ $$87^3 - 79^3 = 165464 = 38^3 + 48^3 = 20^3 + 54^3$$ $$202^3 - 171^3 = 3242197 = 85^3 + 138^3 = 76^3 + 141^3$$ I thought it would be worth mentioning :)

Comment: And $229^3 - 192^3 = 4931101 = 102^3 + 157^3 = 76^3 + 165^3$ and another $256^3 - 255^3 = 195841 = 22^3 + 57^3 = 9^3 + 58^3$

Comment: And $419^3 - 362^3 = 26122131 = 235^3 + 236^3 = 107^3 + 292^3$ and also $391^3 - 382^3 = 4033503 = 87^3 + 150^3 = 24^3 + 159^3$ and just one more, $453^3 - 397^3 = 30388904 = 234^3 + 260^3 = 26^3 + 312^3$

Comment: Oh, and $517^3 - 436^3 = 55306557 = 285^3 + 318^3 = 6^3 + 381^3$. There are infinitely many

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the paper *[Characterizing the Sum of Two Cubes](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL6/Broughan/broughan25.pdf)*, Kevin Broughan gives the relevant theorem,

***Theorem:*** Let $N$ be a positive integer. Then the equation $N = x^3 + y^3$ has a solution in positive integers $x,y$ if and only if the following conditions are satisfied:

1. There exists a divisor $m|N$ with $N^{1/3}\leq m \leq (4N)^{1/3}.$
2. And $\sqrt{m^2-4\frac{m^2-N/m}{3}}$ is an integer.

The sequence of integers $F(n)$,

$$\begin{aligned}
F(n) 
&= a^3+b^3 = (2 n + 6 n^2 + 6 n^3 + n^4)^3 + (n + 3 n^2 + 3 n^3 + 2 n^4)^3\\
&= c^3+d^3 = (1 + 4 n + 6 n^2 + 5 n^3 + 2 n^4)^3 + (-1 - 4 n - 6 n^2 - 2 n^3 + n^4)^3
\end{aligned}$$

for integer $n>3$ *apparently* is expressible as a sum of two *positive* integer cubes in *exactly* and *only* two ways.

$$\begin{aligned}
F(4) &= 744^3+756^3 = 945^3+15^3\\
F(5) &= 1535^3+1705^3 = 2046^3+204^3\\
&\;\vdots\\
F(60) &=14277720^3+26578860^3 = 27021841^3+12506159^3
\end{aligned}$$

Using Broughan's theorem, I have tested $F(n)$ from $n=4-60$ and, *per $n$, it has only two solutions $m$*, implying in that range it is a sum of two cubes in only two ways.  Can somebody with a faster computer and better code test it for a higher range and see when (if ever) the proposed statement breaks down? Incidentally, we have the nice relations,

$$a+b = 3n(n+1)^3$$

$$c+d = 3n^3(n+1)$$

***Note***: $F(60)$ is already *much* beyond the range of [taxicab](http://oeis.org/A011541) $T_3$ which is the smallest number that is the sum of two positive integer cubes in ***three*** ways.

$$T_3 \approx 444.01^3 = 167^3+436^3 = 228^3+423^3 = 255^3+414^3$$

(Using the theorem, this yields 3 values for $m$.)

Comment: I don't know how you came up with this, but it looks great. I know you have to be careful with these things, seeing as you for small numbers don't have a lot of cubes to choose from, but being true for all of $F(4),\ldots,F(26)$ sounds promising.

Comment: @HowDoIMath: I found Broughan's theorem that enabled me to test $F(4),\dots,F(60)$. Now it is even more promising.

Comment: This is a nice find! As far as I can tell from having skimmed the proof in Broughan's paper, then the $m$ in the two decompositions of $F(n)$ as a sum of two cubes correspond to $m_1=3n^4+9n^3+9n^2+3n$ and to $m_2=3n^3+3n^4$ (here $m=u+v$, where $F(n)=u^3+v^3$). By the theorem, $\sqrt{m^2-4\frac{m^2-F(n)/m}{3}}$ is integer for $m=m_i$, $i=1,2$, The real question is then if $\sqrt{m^2-4\frac{m^2-F(n)/m}{3}}$ is integer for any *other* values of $m$, such that $m|F(n)$. This looks like a non-trivial problem though. :)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: See [**Leonhard Euler**, *Disquitiones Artithmeticae*, Vol. I, Ch. $272$, Pag. $556-576$](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6952c/f599.highres).

Comment: This holds for $N\le 200$. I'm not clear on how you came up with this formula, though, even given the paper quoted.

Comment: @rogerl: You mean $F(n)$? I've now forgotten where I found this. I re-checked Broughan's paper and it's not from there. Hm...

Answer (score 4):

As for the question regarding whether or not there are infinitely many numbers that can be expressed as the sum of two cubes in two different ways or not, there's a very quick and simple way to prove this. Since you have 
$$ 1729 = 10^3 + 9^3 = 12^3 + 1^3 $$ 
Multiply both sides by $ n^3 $ where $ n $ is a positive integer to get 
$$ 1729 n^3 = (10n)^3 + (9n)^3 = (12n)^3 + n^3 $$ 
and there you have it, plug in any value for $ n $ and and you have your proof for the infinitude of such numbers. Obviously this doesn't include all the solutions but it proves that there certainly are an infinite number of them

Comment: It is obvious that such numbers have _at least_ two representations as a sum of two cubes, but is it obvious that they have _exactly_ two?

Comment: No, well not to me it isn't.

Comment: If $(10n)^3 + (9n)^3 = (an + b)^3 + (cn + d)^3$ then $b^3 + d^3$ must be 0 modulo $n$, and if $d$ is invertible then $bd^{-1}$ must be a cube root of $-1$ modulo $n$. So you can choose $n$ from the primes of the form $3k + 2$, of which there are infinitely many, then there is no such cube root of $-1$, so $b$ and $d$ must be multiples of $n$, and the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

I found a number recently which can be expressed as a sum of two cubes in exactly two different ways.

```
  65673928=164³+394³=103³+401³
```