# Diophantine cubic equations

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Specifically I mean the equation:
$$x^3+y^3=u^3+v^3+w^3.$$
It is relatively easy to find a solution (in this case) by guessing:
$$7^3+8^3=1^3+5^3+9^3.$$
However, I don't know whether that solution is unique. So my question is if there is some algorithm to deal with that kind of equations and, more importantly, if there is not solution, there is one solution, or there are several solutions. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are you allowing non-positive integers or not (excluding trivial cases like $u=x,v=y,w=0$?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A085336 is pertinent

Comment: The Accepted Answer to [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274816/numbers-that-can-be-expressed-as-the-sum-of-two-cubes-in-exactly-two-different-w) links to an interesting 2003 paper "Characterizing the sum of two cubes" by KA Broughan.

Comment: Remarkably (to me at least) your solution also satisfies $x+y=u+v+w$, as does that in Sam's answer and several of those in Robert Israel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some solutions:
$$ \eqalign{13^3 + 14^3 &= 1^3 + 3^3 + 17^3\cr
7^3 + 8^3 &= 1^3 + 5^3 + 9^3\cr
7^3 + 21^3 &= 1^3 + 14^3 + 19^3\cr
17^3 + 18^3 &= 1^3 + 14^3 + 20^3\cr
7^3 + 9^3 &= 2^3 + 4^3 + 10^3\cr
14^3 + 16^3 &= 2^3 + 10^3 + 18^3\cr
5^3 + 15^3 &= 3^3 + 9^3 + 14^3\cr
2^3 + 19^3 &= 3^3 + 14^3 + 16^3\cr
10^3 + 21^3 &= 3^3 + 15^3 + 19^3\cr
1^3 + 7^3 &= 4^3 + 4^3 + 6^3\cr
14^3 + 18^3 &= 4^3 + 8^3 + 20^3\cr
7^3 + 16^3 &= 4^3 + 10^3 + 15^3\cr
10^3 + 21^3 &= 4^3 + 13^3 + 20^3\cr
11^3 + 17^3 &= 5^3 + 14^3 + 15^3\cr
12^3 + 20^3 &= 5^3 + 14^3 + 19^3\cr
7^3 + 11^3 &= 6^3 + 9^3 + 9^3\cr
10^3 + 14^3 &= 6^3 + 11^3 + 13^3\cr
3^3 + 15^3 &= 7^3 + 11^3 + 12^3\cr
5^3 + 19^3 &= 7^3 + 12^3 + 17^3\cr
2^3 + 14^3 &= 8^3 + 8^3 + 12^3\cr
3^3 + 21^3 &= 10^3 + 15^3 + 17^3\cr
7^3 + 17^3 &= 11^3 + 12^3 + 13^3\cr
3^3 + 21^3 &= 12^3 + 12^3 + 18^3\cr
14^3 + 22^3 &= 12^3 + 18^3 + 18^3\cr
5^3 + 22^3 &= 13^3 + 14^3 + 18^3\cr
3^3 + 26^3 &= 14^3 + 19^3 + 20^3\cr
}$$

If $(x,y,u,v,w)$ is a solution, then so is $(tx,ty,tu,tv,tw)$ for any positive integer $t$, so there are infinitely many solutions.  But I suspect there are infinitely many even if you require $\text{gcd}(x,y,u,v,w)=1$.

EDIT: For example, given the solution $7^3 + 8^3 = 1^3 + 5^3 + 9^3$, we might look for solutions $(x,y,u,v,w)$ such that $x=7 u$ and $v = 5 u$.  Then $u,w,y$ must satisfy $217 u^3 + y^3 - w^3 = 0$.  Letting $a = u/w$ and $b = y/w$, we are looking
for rational solutions to $217 a^3 + b^3 - 1 = 0$.  That turns out to be an elliptic curve.  After turning it into  Weierstrass form $A^3 - B^3 - 1271403/4 = 0$, Sage tells me this has rank $2$.  Therefore there should be infinitely many solutions of
the given form.  For example, the generators, according to Sage, are $A = 273/4$, $B = 63/8)$, which corresponds to $a=26/125, b=-123/125$, and $A = 93, B=1395/2$,
 which  corresponds to $a=1/6$, $b = -1/6$.

Answer (score 1):

Above equation shown below:

$x^3+y^3=u^3+v^3+w^3$ --------(1)

Equation (1) has parametric solution & is shown below;

$x=8(p-1)^2$

$y=(7p^2-16p+8)$

$u=(3p-2)(3p-4)$

$v=(p-2)(5p-4)$

$w=(p)^2$

For,  $p=3$ we get:

$32^3+23^3=35^3+11^3+9^3$

Comment: How did you get the parametric solution?

Answer (score 0):

$$X_{1}^{3}+X_{2}^{3}+X_{3}^{3}=X_{4}^{3}+X_{5}^{3}$$

I kind of wrote 5 parametric solution.

$$X_{1}=6ca^{2}(k-p)(t-p)$$

$$X_{2}=c^{3}p^{2}+(3a^{3}t-(3a^{3}+2c^{3})k)p+c^{3}k^{2}+3a^{3}kt-3a^{3}t^2$$

$$X_{3}=c^{3}p^{2}+((3a^{3}-2c^{3})k-3a^{3}t)p+c^{3}k^{2}-3a^{3}kt+3a^{3}t^{2}$$

$$X_{4}=(c^{3}-6a^{3})p^{2}+(9a^{3}t+(3a^{3}-2c^{3})k)p+c^{3}k^{2}-3a^{3}kt-3a^{3}t^{2}$$

$$X_{5}=(c^{3}+6a^{3})p^{2}-(9a^{3}t+(3a^{3}+2c^{3})k)p+c^{3}k^{2}+3a^{3}kt+3a^{3}t^{2}$$

For the case when  $k=p$ or  $t=p$.... get the formula for 4 cubes...

Answer (score 0):

$x^3+y^3=u^3+v^3+w^3\tag{1}$
We can get infinitely many integer solutions from a known solution.
Let $[1,-1,1,-1,0]$ is a known solution for equation $(1)$.
Substitute  $x=mt+1, y=t-1, u=t+1, v=nt-1, w=t+0$  to equation $(1)$, then we get 
$$(m^3-1-n^3)t^3+(3m^2-6+3n^2)t^2+(3m-3n)t=0$$ 
Let $m = n$ then $t = 6n^2-6$.
Then we get a parametric solution below.
$$x = 6n^3-6n+1$$
$$y = 6n^2-7$$
$$u = 6n^2-5$$
$$v = 6n^3-6n-1$$
$$w = 6(n-1)(n+1)$$
n is arbitrary.
Thus, we get infinitely many integer solutions from a known solution.

Example:  $n=2..5,$ 
$[x,y,u,v,w]=[37, 17, 19, 35, 18], [145, 47, 49, 143, 48], [361, 89, 91, 359, 90], [721, 143, 145, 719, 144]$

Comment: $\Pi$vhhhcdghjjgffgy